# Multiple .env setup in CI/CD

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, environment-variables

a question about multiple `.env` files and best practices to handle them with `docker-compose.yml` or `gitlab-ci.yml`.

**SCENARIO**

I have a basic setup with a couple of services defined in `docker-compose.yml` and a `gitlab-ci.yml` file that runs the build, tests etc. in Gitlab pipelines. On local, there's also a  `.env` file.

In `docker-compose.yml`, I load the `.env` file with

```
service_name:
  env_file:
    - .env
```

The loaded environment variables contain:

1. Passwords.
2. Configuration eg. `DOMAIN_NAME`. I load this in `docker-compose.yml` with `${ENV_VAR}`.

So far so good.

**PROBLEM**

This `.env` file should be omitted from source control since it contains passwords. That causes builds in Gitlab pipelines to fail since `${ENV_VAR}` is not defined anymore.

In my use-case, the passwords are not required to build, but the configuration is.

**SOLUTION?**

Possible solutions were:

1. Define the configuration variables in Gitlab UI under Settings/CI/CD/Variables.
2. Use `export` to inject them into the container during pipelines.

These solutions do seem error-prone.

**IDEAL SOLUTION?**

It were best to define multiple `.env` files, eg. `master.env` (with configuration), `local.env` (with passwords) etc.

Only `master.env` is part of source control and `local.env` is not. During build on pipelines, it must not break due to missing `local.env`.

What is the best practice to achieve this with `docker-compose.yml` & gitlab-ci.yml`?